# SQL Select multi items as something where there values = 1,2 and 3

Tags: sql, sql-server

So i would like to select a few values separated by a comma into a comment field where the values equal certain matches.

Here is how my table looks.

```
[dbo].[ValuationDetail](
[ValuationDetailId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[ValuationId] [int] NOT NULL,
[TagName] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
[TagValue] [varchar](max) NULL,
[Mod] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[IncludePdf] [bit] NOT NULL,
[IsBinary] [bit] NOT NULL,
```

[image]

I would like to do something like.

```
SELECT 
  ValuationId,
  TagValue as Comment WHERE TagName = 'Sale_8_township', 'Sale_8_portion', 'Sale_8_erf'
WHERE ValuationId = 21702
```

Result being

Comment = ST HELENA BAY,0,1719

Please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: [`WHERE TagName IN (Tag1, Tag2, Tag3)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx)

Comment: How can a single value be equal with three different values? You mean `1,2 or 3` not _and_.

Comment: SELECT 
  ValuationId,
  TagValue as Comment 
WHERE ValuationId = 123
AND TagName IN (Tag1, Tag2, Tag3)

Comment: I would like to build a comment field from the value fields where there name equals different values.

Comment: Added a picture and an example of the result i'm looking for. Hope that helps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concatenate many rows into a single text string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string)

Answer (score 0):

You need something like [GROUP_CONCAT](http://groupconcat.codeplex.com) of MySQL

```
SELECT 
  ValuationId,
  GROUP_CONCAT(TagValue) as Comment 
FROM table
WHERE TagName IN (Tag1, Tag2, Tag3)
AND ValuationId = 123
GROUB BY ValuationId
```

if you don't want to create a new function in SQL Server, you can workaround with the STUFF built in function :

```
STUFF(
         (SELECT ', ' + TagValue
          FROM table
          WHERE ValuationId = outer. ValuationId
          FOR XML PATH (''))
          , 1, 1, '')  AS Comment
```

Comment: *aleroot Group_Concat is not recognized as a built in function name. and i am not understanding the Stuff. STUFF(
         (SELECT ', ' + TagValue
          FROM ValuationDetail
          WHERE ValuationId = 21701 AND TagName = 'comparable_sale_1_sales_price' OR 'comparable_sale_2_sale_price' OR 'comparable_sale_3_sale_price' 
          FOR XML PATH (''))
          , 1, 1, '')  AS Comment

Comment: *aleroot Please look at my edit to get a better idea of what i am trying to achieve

Comment: @Pomster Follow the link on codeplex and add the group_concat function ...  http://groupconcat.codeplex.com

Answer (score 0):

Coalesce helped me concatenate the string stored in a temp table.

```
SELECT @Comment = COALESCE(@Comment + ',','') + TagValue FROM #TempComment
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE #TempComment (id int, TagValue varchar(500))

INSERT INTO #TempComment
        SELECT
            CASE
                WHEN TagName = @saleErf THEN  1
                WHEN  TagName = @salePortion THEN 2
                WHEN  TagName = @saleTownship THEN 3
                WHEN  TagName = @salePrice THEN 4
                WHEN  TagName = @saleDate THEN 5
                WHEN  TagName = @saleOverall THEN 6
            END,
            TagValue
        FROM ValuationDetail
        WHERE TagName IN (@saleErf,@salePortion,@saleTownship, @salePrice, @saleDate, @saleOverall) AND ValuationId = @ValuationId

SELECT @Comment = COALESCE(@Comment + ',','') + TagValue FROM #TempComment ORDER BY Id
```